# Android Facebook SDK: Back-Button woes

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am using the Facebook Android SDK to login from my android app and post to the user's wall. The Facebook posting routine is a separate Intent from my main app.

When there is no network connection, or poor signal, I want to be able to hit the back button (hardware) and cancel the facebook Intent. I can trap for the back button and get back into my main app but the facebook SDK must spin up a thread which is still trying to open the connection.

About a minute after I cancel, the main app blows-up as the facebook connect thread times-out and returns control in my AuthListener.

```
AndroidRuntime  E  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@40bb3de0 is not valid; is your acti
                                  vity running?
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:447)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:283)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.facebook.android.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.onPageStarted(FbDialog.java:180)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:265)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
 26860         AndroidRuntime  E        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I cancel the Facebook connect process gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, I had to specifically remove the authListeners and LoginListeners before finish()'ing so they wouldn't be given control after the connect thread terminates.

```
if (mAuthListener != null)
{
    Log.d (TAG, "removing listerners");
    SessionEvents.removeAuthListener (mAuthListener);
    SessionEvents.removeLogoutListener (mLogoutListener);
}
```

In the Facebook FbDialog.java library source, I also needed to make some changes. A thread (Network connector I think) would still run and after it was done, try and display the login page. There was no view to do it however, and things went kaflooey. I took the cancel routine from the onReceivedError() method but instead of inventing and errorCode or description, I just changed mListener.onError... to mListener.cancel().  Seems to work OK so far...

```
// FbDialog.java
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private boolean mCanceled = false;
```

...

```
    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
      // cancel everything if hardware Back button is hit
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
      {
         mCanceled = true;

         if (mSpinner != null)
           if (mSpinner.isShowing ())
             mSpinner.cancel ();

         mListener.onCancel ();
         FbDialog.this.dismiss ();
         return (true);
      }

      return (false);
    }
```

...

```
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       mCanceled = false;
       ...
    }

    public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
       ...         
       // only show the progress dialog if we've not been canceled
       // this was part of the problem with leaked memory after canceling
       if (mCanceled == false)
         mSpinner.show ();
    }
```

...

```
    public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
    {
       // only dismiss if dialog is showing
       if (mSpinner.isShowing ())
         mSpinner.dismiss ();
    }
```